# Laravel nova - how to edit index page on resource

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-nova, openstack-nova

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL0Ea.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mm8fF.png)

there are only number (ID) but I would like to watch category_name, Not id. When i push button RU need to watch on Russian language When i push to En need to watch in English language. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

need to add method: ->displayUsingLabels()

```
Select::make('Size')->options([
'S' => 'Small'
])->displayUsingLabels(),
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.